# What does "clear a budget" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in the second episode of the seventh season of *Friends*. The context is
Monica, Chandler, and Phoebe's, Rachel and Monica are pretty much telling Chandler what the wedding plans are.

> Monica: All right, so I haven’t **cleared the budget** with my parents
>   yet, but tell me how this is for music.

Comment: Edited 'budet' typing error in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear something with someone is to gain their approval, OK, go-ahead, sign-off, etc.

Effectively, the implication is that her parents are paying.

Answer (score 1):

It means to seek verification in this context.  But also can be use to check if something permitted.
It's often used in air traffic operations.  Flight 234, you have have clearance, or are cleared, for take-off.